# flex-direction: column in safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I am trying to create a responsive progress bar using flex-direction: column.
So far it is working fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE, but it does not work in Safari.

In Safari the progress bar steps are displayed one under the other instead of in a line.

[image]

My css is obviously missing something. Any ideas?

The css & html code is here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeLJWY

Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.step-indicator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;  
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

}

.step-indicator .step-icon {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #c2c2c2;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

 .step-icon a {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.step.active .step-icon {
  background: #F08B46;
}

.step p {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  color: #c2c2c2;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
}

.step.active p {
  color: #F08B46;
}

.step.step2 p,
.step.step3 p {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.indicator-line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  background: #c2c2c2;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;  
}

.indicator-line.active {
  background: #F08B46;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <section class="step-indicator">
           <div class="step active active"><div class="step-icon"> <a href="#" title="First Step">1</a></div><p>First Step</p></div> <div class="indicator-line  active active"></div>
           <div class="step active"><div class="step-icon"> <a href="#" title="Second Step">2</a></div><p>Second Step</p></div> <div class="indicator-line  active"></div>
           <div class="step"><div class="step-icon"> <a href="#" title="Third Step">3</a></div><p>Third Step</p></div> <div class="indicator-line "></div>
           <div class="step"><div class="step-icon"> <a href="#" title="Done!"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div><p>Done!</p></div>  
 </section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats your safari version ?

Comment: If you are a Windows user then you have to know that Safari is not supporting windows from 6.0 to onwards ... i am a Mac user and i am using safari 11.1 .. and your code is working fine on my side

Comment: Try removing `width: 100%` from `.indicator-line`.

Comment: Thanks Michael_B. I am using v.5.1. I tried removing width: 100% from .indicator-line but it didn't make any difference.